# What are the specific difference between event hubs and Hdinsight in azure for Kafka?

Tags: azure, apache-kafka, azure-eventhub

Im working on an application where I need to choose between Hdinsight and event hubs. I have completely searched the internet but could not find any specific comparison between them. I would like to know it from some experienced azure users.

P.S this isn't an opinion based question.

Answer (score 6):

HDInsight installs and runs Kafka on their servers. So whatever Kafka release they install you get the entire feature set from that very release.

On the other hand, Azure Event Hubs support Kafka protocol on its own implementation of event streaming solution. So basically it is not Kafka running behind the scenes but Kafka clients can still talk to this service since client protocol is binary compliant with Kafka. Please note that Event Hubs don't support all Kafka features today. Here is a list of missing features:

Idempotent producer

Transaction Compression

Size-based retention

Log compaction

Adding partitions to an existing topic

HTTP Kafka API

Kafka Streams

Comment: Thanks alot.. so, in terms of pricing event hubs are a better choice. right?

Comment: I cannot really compare pricing between both. Azure Event Hubs is priced on throughput units where 1 unit allows 1MB/sec ingress and 2MB/sec egress. On the other hand HDInsight is priced on VM types.

Comment: Azure Event hubs does support Idempotent producers for Kafka 

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/apache-kafka-frequently-asked-questions#does-azure-event-hubs-support-apache-kafka-idempotent-producers-and-consumers-

Comment: A good list of differences between Kafka (assume similar on HDInsight and Event Hubs) including decision tree

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/guide/hadoop/apache-kafka-migration